# The real 2019 solution to disable chrome autofill

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, forms

I know this question has a lot of answers. I have looked through all the solutions to disable google autocomplete(the drop down of suggestions), like using autocomplete=0ff or autocomplete=false, but nothing has solved the issue. 
I have created an MVC app that has views with dropdown lists and HTML EditorFor.

One solution to add a name to the HTML editor for, helped to remove autocomplete, however since I changed the name of the HTML EditorFor, I had an issue posting back the value.

```
<div class="col-md-10">
     @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address, new {htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @id = "show_address", Name = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), autocomplete = "noped" } })
</div>
```

Does anybody have a solution for 2019 to disable the google autocomplete?

**Update:**

I tried using html.textboxfor(as given in the first solution below), however I have realised that autocomplete=off only works if there is one other textboxfor in the view. **If there is multiple textboxfor in the same view, using autocomplete=off on any of the Html Textboxfor will not work for any of them to disable autocomplete!** Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I have found the answer. I give credit for @Mangesh Ati for this solution. I just wanted to summarise the solution for anyone else interested.

autocomplete=off works to disable google autosuggestions on all @htmlTextBoxFor, **besides** for the part of model called **address**, instead use autocomplete=randomn_string

Important:
If you are using a jquery autocomplete on the textboxfor..its important to add the attribute of autocomplete=randomn_string on .focus like below:

```
 $('#show_address').autocomplete({

            }).focus(function () {
                 $(this).attr('autocomplete', 'some_random_value');

            });
```

Comment: Thanks !! for credit. finally, you found your solution

Comment: For me, the autocomplete = "random" works fine at the TextBoxFor level.  If you want to apply it at the FORM level, there what works is autocomplete = "off". Tested in Chrome 79.

Comment: Your solution is partialy correct since the first input field keeps displaying suggestions... any idea ? I even removed the focus attribute or tried to specify a random autocomplete value directly on the form tag but no changes :/

Comment: Actually, I had the 'name' attribute of the input tag set to 'Name' which caused the suggestion to be displayed. Changing the name to something like 'ClientName' solved the issue...

Comment: .... Actually, changing the name attribute only changes the 'key' that holds the suggestion in the browsers cache... which means the suggestions will start to appear again once the name has been changed

Answer (score 2):

EditorFor is having its own some disadvantages, it did not work in some scenarios, a better way to use TextBoxFor instead of EditorFor.Also, It did not affect Postback value.(For more details [check here](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/2924/how-to-control-the-output-of-htmleditorfor-in-aspnet-mvc))

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Address, new { @class = "form-control",  @id = "show_address", autocomplete = "off" })
```

**UPDATE**: Check my updated demo [DEMO](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ePJEU6)
After adding autocomplete=off, still some browser ignores them and they try to show you some hint or autofill. More info [check this](https://gist.github.com/niksumeiko/360164708c3b326bd1c8) 
Add some random_value in autocomplete, so browsers consider as an off.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Address1, new { @class = "form-control",  @id = "show_address", autocomplete = "some_random_value" })
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try?

```
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(
    model => model.date, 
    new { @class = "aDatePicker", autocomplete = "off" }
)%>
```

It will generate markup that is close to the following:

```
<input type="text" id="date" name="date" class="aDatePicker" autocomplete="off" />
```

Also you can try:

```
//Disable autocomplete throughout the site
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input:text,form").attr("autocomplete","off");
})
```

Comment: Thanks! The above code works but when i use the above first solution for  multiple textboxfor, then no autocomplete is disabled in any of textboxfor!Do you know why?

Comment: Check the rendered code and see what is the difference between working and non working rendered code!

Comment: I tried checking the difference, by checking how the elements are are rendered, however developer tools shows the input as autocomplete=off, even though the google autocomplete has not been disabled for that input. Can you advise me how to check further or any solution..? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In VB this worked for me (use C# converter):

```
@Html.EditorFor(Function(m) m.Password, New With {.class = "form-control text-center", .autocomplete = "new-password"})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="any" readonly onfocus="this.removeAttribute('readonly');">
```